# Heroku Errors due to sqlite gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi everyone I recieve the following error when trying to push my app to my heroku. I have tried uninstalling the sqlite gem but it does not seem to work. Any suggestions? Here is my heroku logs:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
       Installing rake 10.4.2
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing json 1.8.2
       Installing minitest 5.6.1
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing activesupport 4.2.0
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing mini_portile 0.6.2
       Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2
       Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
       Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
       Installing loofah 2.0.2
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
       Installing actionview 4.2.0
       Installing rack 1.6.1
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing actionpack 4.2.0
       Installing globalid 0.3.5
       Installing activejob 4.2.0
       Installing mime-types 2.6.1
       Installing mail 2.6.3
       Installing actionmailer 4.2.0
       Installing activemodel 4.2.0
       Installing arel 6.0.0
       Installing activerecord 4.2.0
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.10
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
       Installing execjs 2.5.2
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing railties 4.2.0
       Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
       Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Installing responders 2.1.0
       Installing warden 1.2.3
       Installing devise 3.4.1
       Installing multi_json 1.11.0
       Installing jbuilder 2.2.16
       Installing jquery-rails 4.0.3
       Using bundler 1.9.7
       Installing sprockets 3.1.0
       Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.1
       Installing rails 4.2.0
       Installing rdoc 4.2.0
       Installing sass 3.4.14
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing sass-rails 5.0.3
       Installing sdoc 0.4.1
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /tmp/build_ef2c5d45f3ed3dc1ba8f435dfdd85c00/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
       'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
       and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_ef2c5d45f3ed3dc1ba8f435dfdd85c00/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_ef2c5d45f3ed3dc1ba8f435dfdd85c00/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_ef2c5d45f3ed3dc1ba8f435dfdd85c00/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot
       continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
       Installing rake 10.4.2
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing json 1.8.2
       Installing minitest 5.6.1
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing activesupport 4.2.0
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing mini_portile 0.6.2
       Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2
       Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
       Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
       Installing loofah 2.0.2
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
       Installing actionview 4.2.0
       Installing rack 1.6.1
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing actionpack 4.2.0
       Installing globalid 0.3.5
       Installing activejob 4.2.0
       Installing mime-types 2.6.1
       Installing mail 2.6.3
       Installing actionmailer 4.2.0
       Installing activemodel 4.2.0
       Installing arel 6.0.0
       Installing activerecord 4.2.0
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.10
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
       Installing execjs 2.5.2
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing railties 4.2.0
       Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
       Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Installing responders 2.1.0
       Installing warden 1.2.3
       Installing devise 3.4.1
       Installing multi_json 1.11.0
       Installing jbuilder 2.2.16
       Installing jquery-rails 4.0.3
       Using bundler 1.9.7
       Installing sprockets 3.1.0
       Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.1
       Installing rails 4.2.0
       Installing rdoc 4.2.0
       Installing sass 3.4.14
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing sass-rails 5.0.3
       Installing sdoc 0.4.1

       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

       /tmp/build_ef2c5d45f3ed3dc1ba8f435dfdd85c00/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
       'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
       and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.

       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_ef2c5d45f3ed3dc1ba8f435dfdd85c00/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/


       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_ef2c5d45f3ed3dc1ba8f435dfdd85c00/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_ef2c5d45f3ed3dc1ba8f435dfdd85c00/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot
       continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !
```

My gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :production do
   gem 'pg'
   gem 'rails_12factor'
 end

 group :development do
   gem 'sqlite3'
 end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
# Devise for User Creation/Authentication
gem 'devise'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

My gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rack (~> 1.6.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.0)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (5.0.0)
      columnize (= 0.9.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.4.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.5.2)
    globalid (0.3.5)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.2.16)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.2)
    loofah (2.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.6.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.6.1)
    multi_json (1.11.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.18.2)
    rack (1.6.1)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activerecord (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.0)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
    responders (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5)
    sass (3.4.14)
    sass-rails (5.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    spring (1.3.6)
    sprockets (3.1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.10)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.1.2)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  devise
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  pg
  rails (= 4.2.0)
  rails_12factor
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)
```

Sorry for all the code, but I am frustrated that I can't find the error. Thanks again.

Best, 
Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `bundle update` and commit again before pushing

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Gemfile.lock has sqllite from your development group in your gemfile.  You could try:

```
bundle install --without development
```

and committing that Gemfile.lock

Better would be to just remove sqllite as a development dependency.